# floating element into a centered element

Tags: html, css, centering, responsive

I'm not sure how I would go about centering an image and then have a link floated up against the right side of the image and maintain the images position of true center. The following image is a mock up of what I am attempting.

I'm hoping there's a simple way to accomplish this using only css

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: There is no image.

Comment: Here is a link to the example image http://www.appalachiadesigns.com/images/centering_example.png

Comment: don't use a float, use display:inline-block or display: table-cell, you'll be much happier with the results

Answer (score 0):

You can use [positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) to set the image to horizontal center with setting `margin: 0 auto` on the wrapper and the text in absolute position to this centered wrapper `div`:

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 150px;
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper a {
  position: absolute;
  right: -100px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="http://example.com">Learn more &gt;</a>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
</div>
```

Comment: @JonVanDenEeden I'm glad I could help. I would appreciate an upvote/accept :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it.

Apply `position: relative` to both the image and the link.  Set a left margin of 50% to the image.

Use the left offset to move both the image and the link over by half the width of the image (assuming the image has a fixed/non-responsive width).

Using the left margin on the link to control the white space between the image and the link.

```css
.wrap {
  border: 1px dashed gray;
}
img {
  margin-left: 50%;
  position: relative;
  left: -50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
a { 
  position: relative;
  left: -50px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
  <a href="">Learn More</a>
</div>
```